# listbox column head format backcolor

Tags: ms-access-2007

I need to set the entire column head in the list box to bold
and color. So I created a list box, and in the list box property under
column heads I selected yes, how can I make this list box bold without
effect the rest of the data in the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it as far as I know.  The only alternative I can offer is a method I use.  You make your list box wide enough that it doesn't scroll horizontally and put labels right above it.

[image: example]

Remember to leave the last column a little wider than you need to account for the scroll bar.